# RavenDB Connecting To Embedded Document Store During Unit Test

Tags: .net, ravendb, document-database

### Edit

Turns out I am storing the document correctly so the beginning part of this question is not correct, probably due to my inexperience with RavenDB.  However I still have the question of being able to open the RavenDB Management Studio while using an EmbeddableDocumentStore in a unit test.

---

I seem to be running into a problem storing documents in the EmbeddableDocumentStore during a unit test using NUnit.  In order to see if I am actually storing the document I am trying to connect to the embedded database.

When trying to open the url **http://computername:8080/** (for some reason raven db always uses the computer name on my pc) the browser loading bar just spins and if I stop the unit test and try the url again Chrome just gives me the message that it could not connect. Here's some code for context.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test2 : IDisposable
{
    private EmbeddableDocumentStore _documentStore;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        if (_documentStore != null) return;

        _documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            DataDirectory = "Data",
            RunInMemory = true,
            UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
        };

        _documentStore.Configuration.AnonymousUserAccessMode = AnonymousUserAccessMode.All;

        _documentStore.Initialize();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var document = StaticData.getdocument();

        using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(document);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var test = session.Load<ObjectType>().Length;
            //This is always 0
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _documentStore.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Also I have the Raven.Studio.xap file in the root of my Test project.

I am using VS2012, and .Net 4.5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok so I have looked farther in and it turns out the document is saving successfully, I was able to retrieve it by changing the `Load` statement to `session.Load<ObjectType>(1)`.  So I have updated the question to talk more about opening RavenDB Management Studio using an EmbeddedDocumentStore while in a unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
static public void WaitForUserToContinueTheTest(EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore, bool debug = true)
{
    if (debug && Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        return;

    documentStore.SetStudioConfigToAllowSingleDb();

    documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Put("Pls Delete Me", null,

                                       RavenJObject.FromObject(new { StackTrace = new StackTrace(true) }),
                                       new RavenJObject());

    documentStore.Configuration.AnonymousUserAccessMode = AnonymousUserAccessMode.All;
    using (var server = new HttpServer(documentStore.Configuration, documentStore.DocumentDatabase))
    {
        server.StartListening();
        Process.Start(documentStore.Configuration.ServerUrl); // start the server

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Get("Pls Delete Me") != null && (debug == false || Debugger.IsAttached));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ayende! I can see what this is doing however my one remaining question is where can I find the namespace for `documentStore.SetStudioConfigToAllowSingleDb()`? Resharper can't seem to find it and a search of google and github produced nothing. I have the RavenDB.Client, RavenDB.Database, and RavenDB.Embedded packages installed in my test project.

Answer (score 0):

The exact details of how to apply @Ayende Rahien's solution is missing from his answer, so I'll tell the exact steps here:

1. In case you are creating your EmbeddableDocumentStore with the UseEmbeddedHttpServer set to true, remove it, as the WaitForUserToContinueTheTest creates a server for you.
2. In the test code that you want to debug, call the WaitForUserToContinueTheTest method.
3. Set a breakpoint in Visual Studio after the WaitForUserToContinueTheTest method.
4. When running in debug mode, a browser window with the URL localhost:8080/raven/studio.html or :8080/raven/studio.html should open automatically.
5. To exit the while loop in the WaitForUserToContinueTheTest, use the Raven HTTP GUI and go to "Documents" -> "All documents". On the right side, right click the "Pls delete me" row, and click "Delete". Now Visual Studio should continue your test.

(By the way, I hope the RavenDB team will improve the unit testing documentation better.)